# MySQL Queries with Isotope and InfiniteScroll

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently coding a portfolio / blog-style website using; `MySQL`, `PHP` and `Isotope` by Metafizzy to create a Pintrest style.

The `InfiniteScroll.js` is called once the scroll position reaches the bottom of the div that the content is held in, and it then imports a `'page2.php'` underneath, that contains another `MySQLi` query to display the next set of data. All of the information is being grabbed from a central table. The information can't be ordered correctly in the table, as we want the data displayed to be random on every refresh.

I'm currently using the following statement(s); `'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9'`, then using `'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9 OFFSET 9'` on the second page then increasing the OFFSET by 9 on every page thereafter.

This is giving me duplicate results from the database, I think this is caused by `'RAND()'`. Is there a way to not have the results repeat more than once, while still being random, when the queries are technically on separate pages?

**The following is the code from my index page. I know MySQL is depreciated, I'm purely using it as a proof of concept.**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TonyG Ltd</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


  <?php include 'db/db.php'; $query='SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9' ; $result=m ysql_query($query) or die($myQuery. "<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); $rows=m ysql_num_rows($result); ?>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row nav">
      <div class="button-group filters-button-group">

        <div class="col-xs-5 nav-left"><a class="nav-link" data-filter=".folder-open">PROJECTS</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="nav-link" data-filter=".desktop">SERVICES</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="nav-link" href="blog.php">BLOG</a>
        </div>

        <a data-filter="*">
          <div class="col-xs-2"><span class="nav-logo center-block"></span>
          </div>
        </a>

        <div class="col-xs-5 nav-right"><a class="nav-link" data-filter=".user">PEOPLE</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="nav-link" data-filter=".briefcase">CLIENTS</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="nav-link" href="http://192.168.2.30/~ryanelliott/tonyg/contact">CONTACT</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="heading">
        <h2>TAGLINE</h2>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="container" class="container variable-sizes clearfix infinite-scrolling">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
        <?php while ($row=m ysql_fetch_array($result)) { if ($row[ 'homepage-desc'] !='NULL' ) { echo '<div class="grid-item '.$row[ 'icon']. ' '.$row[ 'icon']. ' grid-item--'. $row[ 'card'] . '" data-category="'.$row[ 'icon']. '"> 
                        <div>
                            <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><div class="image"><img src="'. $row[ 'image-1'] . '" alt=""></div></a>
                            <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><h5 class="hold">'. $row[ 'title'] . '<i class="icon fa fa-'. $row[ 'icon'] . '"></i></h5></a>
                            <p class="light">'. $row[ 'homepage-desc'] . '</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>'; } else { echo '<div class="grid-item '.$row[ 'icon']. ' grid-item--'. $row[ 'card'] . '" data-category="'.$row[ 'icon']. '"> 
                            <div>
                                <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><div class="image"><img src="'. $row[ 'image-1'] . '" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><h5 class="holdfalse">'. $row[ 'title'] . '<i class="icon fa fa-'. $row[ 'icon'] . '"></i></h5></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>'; } } ?>

      </div>

      <nav id="page_nav">
        <a href="autoload/page2.php"></a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
          <p>TonyG Ltd. Registered in ... Number ...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right right-fix">
          <p>studio@tonyg.co.uk | +44(0) 870 121 7676</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/infinite-scroll-master/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        // init Isotope
        var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          percentPosition: true,
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
          }
        });

        $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: '#page_nav', // selector for the paged navigation 
            nextSelector: '#page_nav a', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
            itemSelector: '.grid-item', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
            loading: {
              finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
              img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
            }
          },
          // call Isotope as a callback
          function(newElements) {
            $container.isotope('appended', $(newElements));
          }
        );
      });
    </script>

  </footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**The following is the code for the imported page, that adds the extra content on scroll.**

```html
<?php include '../db/db.php'; $query='SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9' ; $result=m ysql_query($query) or die($myQuery. "<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); $rows=m ysql_num_rows($result); ?>
<div class="container scroll" data-ui="jscroll-default">
  <div class="grid jscroll-inner">
    <div class="grid-sizer col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <?php while ($row=m ysql_fetch_array($result)) { if ($row[ 'homepage-desc'] !='NULL' ) { echo '<div class="grid-item '.$row[ 'icon']. ' '.$row[ 'icon']. ' grid-item--'. $row[ 'card'] . '" data-category="'.$row[ 'icon']. '"> 
                        <div>
                            <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><div class="image"><img src="'. $row[ 'image-1'] . '" alt=""></div></a>
                            <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><h5 class="hold">'. $row[ 'title'] . '<i class="icon fa fa-'. $row[ 'icon'] . '"></i></h5></a>
                            <p class="light">'. $row[ 'homepage-desc'] . '</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>'; } else { echo '<div class="grid-item '.$row[ 'icon']. ' grid-item--'. $row[ 'card'] . '" data-category="'.$row[ 'icon']. '"> 
                            <div>
                                <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><div class="image"><img src="'. $row[ 'image-1'] . '" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><h5 class="holdfalse">'. $row[ 'title'] . '<i class="icon fa fa-'. $row[ 'icon'] . '"></i></h5></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>'; } } ?>

  </div>

  <div class="next jscroll-next-parent">
    <a href="autoload/page3.php">next</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please, no text but some code. It's impossible to find the problem just by explaining your algo.

Comment: Can we see the end result? I've had to do a couple of these myself, so I always like to see what others come up with.

Comment: @Ryan you just have to change your query. see my answer below

Comment: I think you could store a random value on page refresh and use that as the seed for RAND() - so RAND($seed). Try that, and see if it works. Javascript also has a random number method, so you could use that as the seed.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your input, really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the occasion overlap using your 'RAND($seed)' method :(

Comment: That doesn't sound possible - but maybe I've misunderstood how that works

Comment: Becarfull, you have spaces in your code like for `m ysql_query` instead of `mysql_query` or `m ysql_num_rows` instead of `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: @ThinkTank I think that was caused from using the 'Tidy' option in the HTML editor when creating the post, they're not there on my actual code...strange

Answer (score 0):

First, I suppose you know your job.
Because there is no code in your question, I'll just give you an idea.
You'll have to complete it.

In page 1 you'll store IDs from your first result set in an array and stored this array in $_SESSION.

page1.php

```
session_start();

//Make your query : SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9
//Suppose results are stored in an array called "$listResult".

$listIDs = array();

foreach($listResult as $result)
{
    $listIDs[] = $result['idFromTable'];
}

$_SESSION['listIDs'] = $listIDs;

//Continue your stuff
```

Page 2, you'll retrieve list of IDs from $_SESSION. Then you'll add a where close in your query to select random result which are not matching the list of IDs you stored in page 1.

page2.php

```
session_start();

$strListIDs = implode(',', $_SESSION['listIDs']);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN ('.$strListIDs.') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9 OFFSET 9';
```

Comment: I'll try implementing this now, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I think this is going to get slower as one scrolls through :-(

Comment: I've fed the sql query into your code and it's chucking up this error; **Warning: Illegal string offset 'home_id' in // SITE URL // on line 31**

Answer (score 0):

**Try pure mysql :**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM blog LIMIT 1, 9
) result
ORDER BY rand()
```

**Note :**  1st parameter of limit work like offset

Comment: This would work, if I could use the 'id' column of the database to ensure no duplications occur. I can't use the 'id' column as I have multiple types of 'data' in my db. I have 4 main sections; Projects, Services, Blog and People (I have assigned each section a number, Projects for example uses '601 - 640' in a 'home_id' column). These are all in blocks, so the People have ID's ranging from 11 - 20, so if I use their ID to select them, although they'll be in a random order, there will still be a block of 9 people on the homepage, instead of being mixed up with the other sections.

Comment: @RyanElliott see my updated answer, i removed order by id

Comment: Here's a screenshot [link](https://gyazo.com/b0b734d5e25b7e11b1cff0b02814aeca) of the two ID columns I have in my db. The above method, even without the 'order by id' is still selecting the first 3 from the database, which will all be from the same section '60*'. I hope this is making sense!

Comment: This will work, i think you did not use this query in your code

Comment: Just to prove this doesn't work, please take a look at this screenshot [link](https://gyazo.com/08348e9431903de133b98223effc68c6). As you can see there are 2 images repeated once the 'page2.php' has been activated by the scroll js. And they are also ALL from the Blog section, rather than being mixed up with the other sections, as I mentioned previously...